# how to edit the configuration file of boost in slave using buildbot ShellCommand?

Tags: boost, compilation, cross-compiling, buildbot

So I am trying to build and test boost in the remote slave( mac ). I want to edit tools/build/v2/user-config.jam file so that I could use the toolset=clang.

How can I add

```
//in user-config.jam
// toolset will use clang

using clang
   : ...etc
```

in the user-config.jam file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that unix has a nice little command called

```
echo
```

so what I can do is use this command to edit that file.

```
ShellCommand(
    name = "append config instruction"
    command=['echo','I am adding this configuration cause it was missing','>','~/user-config.jam']
 )
```

This command will add that line in the configuration file.

if you want to make it look like
"I am adding this configuration cause it was missing" I meant to add "" then

```
echo "\"xyz\"" > text.txt
```